# Omega logic, V = Ultimate L and hierarchy of laws collapse

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, multiverse-of-sets

I would like to ask a question about the omega conjecture and its relationship with the V = Ultimate L axiom.

In his lecture Prof. Hugh Woodin have stated that "Assuming the omega conjecture, then from the universal laws of V_omega + 2 one can compute universal laws for V_omega + 3, ..., V_delta where delta is some large cardinal ..., The entire hierarchy of laws collapse". He stated that this cannot possibly be the correct conception of truth.

However further down the lecture he said that if V = Ultimate L then the omega conjecture holds. Does that mean that if V = Ultimate L then the entire hierarchy of laws collapses and the whole V is reduced to truths about the set of real numbers?

That in my mind would be horrible knowing that there is nothing beyond/deeper than truths about the set of real numbers.

Comment: What lecture are you referring to?

Comment: @GabeGoldberg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVF4N1Ix5WI

Comment: I think Woodin is referring to the philosophical arguments against the multiverse view of set theory from his paper "The continuum hypothesis, the generic multiverse of sets, and the $\Omega$ conjecture." He is trying to argue against the view that the only meaningful statements of set theory are the generically invariant ones. So the "universal laws" are probably the generically invariant statements. But there is more to the universe than that, so the situation isn't as horrible as you might think.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg So what collapses to some small fragment of V is truths that hold in the whole multiverse? So in other words only truths about the set of real numbers are the same across the whole generic multiverse and all other truths are universe dependent?

Comment: Yes to the first sentence. Your second sentence is also roughly speaking true (assuming large cardinals), but I wouldn't say it's a reformulation of the first. Also, there are other generically invariant facts, e.g. consequences of ZFC.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg I see. What confused me was that Prof. Woodin rejected this collapse as something that is not good but than also his V = Ultimate L would make it collapse so I was wandering what is happening

Comment: @GabeGoldberg I was afraid that the whole Set theoretic universe or multiverse would be no more complex than the set of real numbers. So would You say, that the set theoretic universe (or multiverse depending on ones taste) is much more complex than the set of real numbers?

Comment: I think Woodin rejects the conception of truth given by generic multiverse truth, and he argues for this rejection based on the collapse of this notion to some level of the cumulative hierarchy. He is not arguing against the collapse (which is a theorem, at least granting the $\Omega$ conjecture). Certainly the universe of sets is more complex than the real numbers. But I think Woodin proved that assuming the $\Omega$-conjecture and the $\text{AD}^+$ conjecture, the invariant $\Pi_2$ theory of the multiverse is not much more complicated than that.

Comment: Whether this is a strong argument against the generic multiverse conception of set theory is up for debate. Toby Meadows has a paper called "Two arguments against the generic multiverse" that examines Woodin's arguments.